# Modifying values with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have XML file with values expressed in SI unit (m, N).
I use an XSLT document to transform it into HTML page where I would like to display values with other units (um, mN).

Is there a way to modify values I extract from my XML document using XSLT without modifying XML content before XSLT processing ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Bertrand

---

Just to notice to others interesting in.
I'm developing in Python, and lxml library allow you to call extensions in XSLT.

http://lxml.de/extensions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do [math in XPath expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-arithmetic):

```
<!-- divide somevalue by 1000 --> 
<xsl:value-of select="somevalue div 1000.0" />
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Do exactly what I want.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you were using c# to run the xslt transform, and the maths capabilities of Xpath are not good enough for your requirements, you can make calls from the xslt to methods in your c# class which would allow you to call out to c# to do your maths and then return the value back into your xslt. Search for c# xslt extensions.

Comment: Will have a look to XSLT extensions.

Comment: And while you're at it, bind the C# to an external web service that calls google's calculator api through an enterprise service bus...

Comment: Thanks for that Pete, I was merely pointing out an option, not suggesting it was the 'right' answer in this case.

Comment: Extensions can be helpful for date parsing and reformatting - there are XSLT stylesheets out there for date processing, but what can be done in 5 lines of C# is humongous in XSLT.